# FileNotFountException for intro.csv in mahout userbased Collaborative filtering recommendation

Tags: java, maven, csv, mahout, mahout-recommender

I created a maven project and in the pom file I added the following dependency

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.mahout</groupId>
        <artifactId>mahout-mr</artifactId>
        <version>0.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

I followed the example in mahout in action and added the RecommenderIntro
 class to src/main/java and copied the intro.csv file into src/main/resource folder.

Error occurs in:

```
DataModel model = new FileDataModel (new File("resources\intro.csv"));

Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: resources/intro.csv
    at org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.model.file.FileDataModel.<init>(FileDataModel.java:180)
    at org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.model.file.FileDataModel.<init>(FileDataModel.java:167)
    at org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.model.file.FileDataModel.<init>(FileDataModel.java:147)
    at recstest.UserBased.main(UserBased.java:19)
```

I also copied the file to main src\main\java and checked and still the same error occurs. What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

Use this to load a resource from your classpath:

```
    URL url = getClass().getResource("/intro.csv");
    Path path = Paths.get(url.toURI());
    File file = path.toFile();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use getResource on the class to get the resource you need

```
DataModel model = new FileDataModel(new File(this.getClass().getResource("/intro.csv").toURI()));
```

Of course you would need to handle possible `URISyntaxException` and `IOException` somehow.